# Clojure Spec on a vararg function

Tags: clojure, specifications, clojure.spec

I am trying to write a spec for a merge function which takes a function and maps as an input and uses function to resolve the conflicts. However the spec i wrote for the function fails. I am trying to figure out how to write spec for such functions.

Below is the code snippet.

```
(require '[clojure.spec.test :as stest])
(require '[clojure.spec :as spec])

(defn deep-merge-with [func & maps] 
  (let [par-func (partial deep-merge-with func)] 
    (if (every? map? maps) 
        (apply merge-with par-func maps) 
        (apply func maps))))

(spec/fdef deep-merge-with
           :args (spec/cat :func (spec/fspec :args (spec/cat :maps (spec/* map?))
                                             :ret map?)
                           :maps (spec/cat :maps (spec/* map?)))
           :ret map?)

(stest/instrument `deep-merge-with)

(deep-merge-with (fn [f s] s) {:a 1} {:a 2})
```

The spec error i am getting is:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Call to #'boot.user/deep-merge-with did not conform to spec:
    In: [0] val: () fails at: [:args :func] predicate: (apply fn),  Wrong number of args (0) passed to: user/eval22001/fn--22002
                                :clojure.spec/args  (#function[boot.user/eval22001/fn--22002] {:a 1} {:a 2})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `[:args :func]` spec:

```
(spec/fspec :args (spec/cat :maps (spec/* map?)) :ret map?)
```

You're saying that the function must accept as arguments *any number* of maps and return a map. But the function you pass to `deep-merge-with` does not conform to that spec:

```
(fn [f s] s)
```

This function takes exactly *two* arguments, not an arbitrary number of maps.

Comment: `(deep-merge-with (fn [& maps] (last maps)) {:a 1} {:a 2}) ` didn't work either, how do we enforce spec on `(fn [f s] s)` to make spec take exactly two arguments.

Comment: @Vijay You could use `(spec/cat :m1 map? :m2 map?)` for an `:args` spec of a function that takes exactly two map arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me debug the issue, I am stupid, my function inputs are not  maps, during the deep merge process when a merge-with func is invoked it actually passes the conflicting values for the function.  so a spec like this will work `(spec/fdef deep-merge-with :args (spec/cat :func (spec/fspec :args (spec/cat :m1 ::spec/any :m2 ::spec/any) :ret ::spec/any) :maps (spec/cat :maps (spec/* ::spec/any))) :ret map?)`

Comment: I don't know how to flag your answer as correct, please help

Comment: @Vijay You should be able to click the gray arrow below the up/down vote buttons next to my post to accept my answer.